# When trying to use ".checked", why is it not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, html.checkbox

When trying to use the ".checked" property, it does not return a true value and therefore I cannot get this test code to alert when checkbox is checked.

```js
var lower = document.querySelector("#lower");

if (lower.checked === true) {
    alert('CHECKED!');
}
```

```html
<li><label for="lower"><input type="checkbox" id="lower">lowercase</label></li>
```

I also tried the following javascript:

```js
var lower = document.querySelector("#lower");

if (lower.checked) {
    alert('CHECKED!');
}
```

also tried it with `document.getElementById("lower")`. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling the code? If it's just at top-level, it runs when the page loads, before the user has had a chance to check the box. You need to put it in an event listener that runs when the user does something.

Comment: It won't run by itself when the user checks the box.

Comment: Your code thinks the checkbox isn't checked because at the time the javascript runs (on page-load), it _isn't_ checked!

Comment: If you are running this code after user has checked the box, it will not work. `.checked` returns the state of the input when the page loads. Any interaction on it after the page load, will not update this property. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#additional_attributes

Comment: @PrerakSola more specifically, an interaction on it after the page loads *will* update the property, but the code that initially checked it's value won't re-run on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch an event for clicking.

By loading the page, the box is not checked.

```js
var lower = document.querySelector("#lower");

lower.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (lower.checked) console.log('CHECKED!');
});
```

```html
<li><label for="lower"><input type="checkbox" id="lower">lowercase</label></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for the `"change"` event in order to have your code run each time the checkbox's state changes.

```js
document.querySelector("#lower").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (this.checked) console.log('CHECKED');
});
```

```html
<li><label for="lower"><input type="checkbox" id="lower">lowercase</label></li>
```